# como obtienes los valores de x e y? Como determinas el final de la pantalla?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas automáticas de una aplicación, uso uiautomatorviewer pero este no me localiza el botón de la flecha para ir hacia atrás. Quiero hacer click con unas coordenadas, pero según el dispositivo, estas coordenadas varían.

Mi idea era poner el eje y hasta el final de la pantalla y después restarle unos pixeles y el eje X hacía el lado derecho. Como podría poner lo del final de la pantalla en este método:

```
public void tapCoordenada(int x, int y) {
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(getDriver());
    touchAction.tap(new PointOption().withCoordinates(x, y)).perform();
}
```

Comment: la pregunta aquí es como obtienes los valores de x y y? Como determinas el final de la pantalla?

Comment: consideraste obtener las dimensiones de la pantalla(o de tu `layaut`)? pongamos que (0,0) es la parte superior izquierda, y sumarle cierto margen a la x e y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo aquí una manera de obtener las coordenadas de touch, espero que te sirva:

```
Display mdisp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point mdispSize = new Point();
mdisp.getSize(mdispSize);
int maxX = mdispSize.x; 
int maxY = mdispSize.y;
```

Para dispositivos que tengan una versión más antigua de API 13:

```
Display mdisp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int maxX= mdisp.getWidth();
int maxY= mdisp.getHeight();
```

(x,y) :-

1) (0,0) es esquina superior izquierda.

2) (maxX,0) es esquina superior derecha

3) (0,maxY) es esquina inferior izquierda

4) (maxX,maxY) es esquina inferior derecha

Comment: Gracias estoy en ello, Como importas `Display` ?

Comment: import android.view.Display; AndroidStudio tiene esta herramienta muy buena que es al pulsar alt+enter en Mac te lo importa automáticamente